# Do I need a transit visa for a layover in Tokyo airport?

Tags: japan, transit-visas, bangladeshi-citizens

My trip will be from Vietnam to Canada. I will have a 4 hr layover in Tokyo.

I am a Bangladeshi passport holder and permanent resident of Canada.

Will I need a transit visa for Tokyo airport?

Comment: Note that Tokyo airport is Haneda, Narita is Narita airport.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Canadian passport then you will be able to get a visa on arrival for 90 days.

Otherwise you might need to apply for a visa before travel.

source : http://www.haneda-airport.com/visa.html

Regarding a transit visa you should also contact your airline; many airlines assist/sponsor a transit visa based on certain conditions